# Create a Personal Access VSTS Token but can't see it

Tags: azure-devops

I need a VSTS Token so that our docker images would authenticate to the private NuGET Feed. After I create a personal access token here https://msasg.visualstudio.com/_details/security/tokens/Edit, then how could I see the value my token? After I create my token, it goes to the page below, but where could I see the value of my token??

[image]

Comment: I didn’t see it when I first created it. I didn’t navigate away but it automatically show me the page I posted above.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. As it says when you generate a token, they are displayed one time and one time only. After you navigate away, you can no longer see the token. This is by design and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem and can confirm that the Token isn't shown at all.
My steps were:

1. Create new Token
2. Typing in a description
3. Edit the checkboxes to my needs
4. Save

After the click on save, I get redirected to the Token Overview Page without showing any Token String. My Guess is, that normally it should show you the Token String at this Point, so that you can copy it.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the PAT (press on "Create Token" on the bottom of the page) you will redirect to all the PAT list **but** in the line of new token you will see the Token value and you can copy it.

I tested it now and I can saw the PAT value after the redirection.

[image]